# Data loss prevention ( or recovery) in a MySql db in embedded systems

Tags: linux, mysql, embedded

I have a problem with a MySql application that write on a SD card or a Compact Flash. After a data loss ( a power failure , for example) , if I try to retrieve the data of my db , it fails and the error code is : incorrect format table. If i try to see the files of my DB in file-system mounted, I obtain:  can't stat file or directory (I/O error).

Someone have suggestion to overcome this? to prevent or recovery the contents of my db?

The scenario is

```
a) a filesystem with ext2 filesystem ( to prevent SD card multiple writings)
b) SD cards or DOM or Compact Flash as physical support
c) the OS ( TinyCore Linux Embedded ) it's loaded in RAM
d) the is MySql MyIsam db
```

Comment: what is your storage engine (MyISAM, InnoDB, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The MYISAM storage engine isn't crash safe, there is no automatic log write plus recovery like there is for InnoDB.
The least you should do is a periodic backup (daily?) to some second storage device or to some other machine, provided your setup has one.